# Delay operator and Apply used when for applying function of a function

Tags: function-construction, programming

I define my own function like that:

```
DelayL1t[(q_: 1) a_[t_]] := q Apply[a, {t - L1[t]/c}]
DelayL2t[(q_: 1) a_[t_]] := q Apply[a, {t - L2[t]/c}]
```

if I just do :

```
DelayL1t[p2[t]]
```

I get

```
p2[t - L1[t]/c]
```

that is correct, but if I do:

```
DelayL2t[DelayL1t[p2[t]]]
```

I get

```
p2[t - L1[t]/c - L2[t - L1[t]/c]/c]
```

while I was expecting to obtain:

```
p2[t - L1[t - L2[t]/c]/c - L2[t]/c]
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
    p2[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c - L2p[t]/c -L3[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c -      L2p[t]/c]/c]

---

I would like to do a series expansion around L_[i,k]/c or L_[i,k]*L[k,i]/c^2 in order to get rid off all the terms where an arm depends on another arms..I was able to do that manually [ I attached my code] does anyone know how to built a function that does it ? It would be nice to have a sort of operator which does series expansion around certain terms! 
thanks in advance!

so once I got the correct time delayed :

```
p2[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c - L2p[t]/c - 
  L3[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c - L2p[t]/c]/c]
```

I did the expansion around  L2p[t]/c:

```
ExpandAll[p2[t - (Normal[Series[L2[t - L2p[t]/c] /.L2p[t]/c -> 
λL2p[t]/c, {λ, 0,1}]] /. λ -> 1)/c 
- L2p[t]/c - L3[t - (Normal[Series[L2[t - L2p[t]/c] /.L2p[t]/c ->
 λ L2p[t]/c, {λ, 0, 1}]] /. λ -> 1)/c - L2p[t]/c]/c]]
```

and I got:

```
     p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c -L3[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c 
+ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2]/c + 
(L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2]
```

then I did the expansion around

```
 {L2[t]/c -> λ L2[t]/c, 
     L2p[t]/c -> λ L2p[t]/c, (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/
      c^2 -> λ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2}
```

that is:

```
    ExpandAll[p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - 
1/c(Normal[Series[L3[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c 
+ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2]/.{L2[t]/c -> λ L2[t]/c, L2p[t]/c -> 
λ L2p[t]/c, (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 -> 
λ(L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2}, {λ, 0, 1}]] 
/.λ -> 1 ) +(L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2]] /. 1/c^3 -> 0
```

and I get:

```
  p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c 
+ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 
+ (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 +
 (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2]
```

I did the final expansion around

```
{(L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/
  c^2 -> λ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2, (
  L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/
  c^2 -> λ (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2, (
  L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/
  c^2 -> λ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2}:


ExpandAll[
 Normal[Series[
     p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c + (
        L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 + (
        L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 + (
        L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2] /. {(
        L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/
        c^2 -> λ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2, (
        L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/
        c^2 -> λ (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2, (
        L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/
        c^2 -> λ (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/
         c^2}, {λ, 0, 1}]] /. λ -> 1 /. 1/c^3 -> 0]
```

and finally I got an expression where all the arm-length terms (L2[t],L3[t] and L2p[t]) do not depends anymore on other arms:

```
p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c] + (
 L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t] Derivative[1][p2][
   t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2 + (
 L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t] Derivative[1][p2][
   t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2 + (
 L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t] Derivative[1][p2][
   t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2
```

Hey you are right!
since it is difficult to explain my intention I upload an immages that show what i need to do! as you can see you where able to help me with the time delay..i was wondering if you are able to do a function that does the series expansion how it is shown.

thank you very much for your kindness

[image: time delay and series expansion]

[image]

Comment: You get what you expect if you flip the two function applications, i.e. `DelayL1t[DelayL2t[p2[t]]]`. Why do you expect this in your case? As far as I can tell, everything works as expected.

Comment: hey lukas first of all thanks! But follow me: if I do DelayL1t[p2[t]] and I get p2[t - L1[t]/c] that is totally correct, when I apply another delay of L2[t]/c to my results :  DelayL2t[DelayL1t[p2[t]]]  I should have that all the things that were depending on time should be delated by L2[t]/c   p2[t-L2[t]/c- L1[t-L2[t]/c]/c] ,instead it flips the index and the delays cannot commute!! I need before to do the delay of L1[t] and that delay has to be delayed again by L2[t].

Comment: @Martina your edited code is very compact and contains expressions which may or may not be interpreted as misstyped input or something else altogether; eg in the second code block there is `\[Lambda]L2p[t]/c` which I assume should be `\[Lambda] L2p[t]/c` but I don't know for sure or what `L_[i,k]*L[k,i]` is supposed to stand for; also in you original code there was no `L3` term; I included such a term in my answer to show that it could be extended to such uses *if* needed; please provide a *clear* instance of your problem as contained as possible eg if the `L3` term is superfluous don't use it

Comment: OK! I put an immage on my answer to help you understand!  after having done the time delay I need to do a taylor expansion around Lk[t]/c for  Lj[t-Lk[t]/c]/c  and then   (1/c [Lk[t]+Lj[t]] + 1/c^2 dot[Lj[t]] Lk[t] for f(t-1/c (Lk[t]+Lj[t])+1/c^2 dot[Lj[t]] Lk[t] )    in order to get the last results.... the only different from the picture is that  for me Lk[t] ,Lj[t]  depends on time even if in the picture  they don't

Comment: @Martina I cannot reproduce anything off of a screen-grab (eg the first line of code is wrong; `delayBy` does not work like that; additionally, in order to get the *first* approximation described in the excerpt you amended your question with, you should use `delaybyApprox` *not* `delayBy` ); please don't use screen-shots unless absolutely necessary; please identify which function-with what input-did not produce the desired output and what that desired output was, in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In your definition

```
DelayL2t[(q_: 1) a_[t_]] := q Apply[a, {t - L2[t]/c}]
```

the pattern `t_` stands not for time but to the whole argument of the input expression. For example, consider the following code:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_[t_]] := {a, t};
f[p2[t - L1[t]/c]]
(*Returns {p2, t - L1[t]/c}*)
```

Therefore, when

```
DelayL2t[p2[t - L1[t]/c]]
```

is evaluated, the kernel takes *the whole construct* `t - L1[t]/c` and substitutes it for `t` in *rhs* of your definition

```
q Apply[a, {t - L2[t]/c}]
```

leading to the result you obtained. If you want to define a function that will delay *symbol t* rather than the argument as a whole, then you should use `ReplaceAll`:

```
ClearAll[delayBy];
delayBy[expr_, l_] := expr /. t -> t - l[t]/c;
delayBy[delayBy[p2[t], l1], l2]
(*Returns p2[t - l1[t - l2[t]/c]/c - l2[t]/c]*)
```

Comment: thank you so much! Do you know how to do a series expansion around L[t]/c to get rid off expr like: p2[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c - L2p[t]/c]/c],    I did :  p2[t - (Normal[Series[L2[t - L2p[t]/c] /. L2p[t]/c -> \[Lambda] L2p[t]/c, {\[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /. \[Lambda] -> 1)/c - L2p[t]/c -  L3[t - (Normal[Series[L2[t -L2p[t]/c] /. L2p[t]/c -> \[Lambda] L2p[t]/c, {\[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /. \[Lambda] -> 1)/c - L2p[t]/c]/c]]

Comment: and I get: p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c -L3[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2] with another expansion I get:          p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - 1/c (Normal[Series[L3[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2] /.{L2[t]/c -> \[Lambda] L2[t]/c, L2p[t]/c -> \[Lambda] L2p[t]/c, (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 -> \[Lambda] (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2}, {\[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /. \[Lambda] -> 1 ) + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2] /.1/c^3 -> 0

Comment: and I get:  p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 + (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2],

Comment: then I do another expansion:  Normal[Series[p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 +(L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 + ( L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2] /. {(
 L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 -> \[Lambda] (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2, (
 L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 -> \[Lambda] (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2, (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 -> \[Lambda] (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2}, {\[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /.\[Lambda] -> 1 /.1/c^3 -> 0]

Comment: and this is the final results:                                                                                     p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c] + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t] Derivative[1][p2][t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2 + (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t] Derivative[1][p2][t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2 + ( L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t] Derivative[1][p2][t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2

Comment: I was wondering if you know a way to automatised the calculation instead of doing it manually step by step, every time i expand around Li[t]/c ->\lambda*Li[t]/c or (Li[t] dot[Lj[t])/c^2 -> \Lambda*(Li[t]dot[Lj[t])/c^2,  thank you in advance for your help, I know I put it in a confused way but i do not know how to include the code in a different way!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand how your implementation of '*delaying*' something works but in order to achieve your desired output you can use the following `delayBy` function.

It receives as input a function (expression) to *delay* and a list of functions that will be used in the implementation of *sequential* delay of the supplied function (*eg* providing `{L1[t],L2[t]}` as an argument will delay the function first by using `L1` and subsequently by using `L2` on the delayed expression from the former iteration).  There are also additional input parameters with default values informed by the details in the question

```
(* main function *)
auxDelayBy[func_, byfuncs_, var_, q_, const_] := Fold[
  With[{h = Head[#1], args = Apply[List, #1], df = #2},
    q Apply[h, (args /. var -> var - df/const)]] &, func, byfuncs]

(* interface function - this is what the user calls *)
delayBy[func_, byfuncs_, var_: t, q_: 1, const_: c] := Which[
  ListQ[byfuncs] && Length[byfuncs] > 1, auxDelayBy[func, byfuncs, var, q, const],
  True, auxDelayBy[func, {byfuncs}, var, q, const]]
```

Evaluating `delayBy[p2[t], L1[t]]` returns

> ```
> p2[t - L1[t]/c]
> ```

while evaluating `delayBy[p2[t], {L1[t], L2[t]}]` returns

> ```
> p2[t - L1[t - L2[t]/c]/c - L2[t]/c]
> ```

Now, assuming that evaluating something like `delayBy[p2[t], {L1[t], L2[t], L3[t]}]` is desirable and it makes sense in the context of the question `delayBy` can accomodate such a request with the following output:

> ```
> p2[t - L1[t - L2[t - L3[t]/c]/c - L3[t]/c]/c - L2[t - L3[t]/c]/c - L3[t]/c]
> ```

---

(*below this line is the answer to the extended question*)

The code below reproduces the results for the first Taylor approximation; the second approximation is relatively trivial and is left for future implementations.

I will provide a code block that is similar but not identical to the previous implementation:

```
delayByApprox[func_, funcs_, var_: t, const_: c, mult_: 1] := 
  Module[{rabbit, thread, counter = 0, x = Last[funcs][var], y = Last[Most[funcs]], rl},

    (* used to implement the cancelation feature - see notes *)
    rl = -y[var - x/const]/const - x/const -> 0;

    rabbit[f_, df_, v_, c_, q_] := q f[v - thread[df[v]/c, counter++]];

    (* provides the required Taylor expansion *)
    thread[expr_, 0] := expr;

    thread[expr_, lvl_] := thread[expr, lvl] = expr + D[expr, x] x;

    (* fold *)
    Fold[
      rabbit[Head[#1], #2, Apply[Sequence][#1], c, mult] &, 
      func[var], Reverse[funcs]] //. rl
  ]
```

Similarly to the previous implementation, evaluating `delayByApprox[p2, {L1, L2, L3}]`

will return

> ```
> p2[t + (L2[t] Derivative[1][L1][t - L2[t]/c])/c^2]
> ```

and (to the extent it makes sense) evaluating `delayByApprox[p2, {L1, L2, L3}]` returns

> ```
> p2[t - L1[t + (L3[t] Derivative[1][L2][t - L3[t]/c])/c^2]/c + (L3[t] Derivative[1][L2][t - L3[t]/c])/c^2 - (L3[t] Derivative[1][L1][t + (L3[t] Derivative[1][L2][t - L3[t]/c])/c^2] (-(1/c) + (2 Derivative[1][L2][t - L3[t]/c])/c^2 - (L3[t] (L2^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t - L3[t]/c])/c^3))/c]
> ```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thank you so much! Do you know how to do a series expansion around L[t]/c to get rid off expr like: p2[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t - L2[t - L2p[t]/c]/c - L2p[t]/c]/c], I did : p2[t - (Normal[Series[L2[t - L2p[t]/c] /. L2p[t]/c -> [Lambda] L2p[t]/c, {[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /. [Lambda] -> 1)/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t - (Normal[Series[L2[t -L2p[t]/c] /. L2p[t]/c -> [Lambda] L2p[t]/c, {[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /. [Lambda] -> 1)/c - L2p[t]/c]/c]]

Comment: and I get: p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c -L3[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2] with another expansion I get: p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - 1/c (Normal[Series[L3[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2] /.{L2[t]/c -> [Lambda] L2[t]/c, L2p[t]/c -> [Lambda] L2p[t]/c, (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 -> [Lambda] (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2}, {[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /. [Lambda] -> 1 ) + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2] /.1/c^3 -> 0

Comment: and I get: p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 + (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2],

Comment: then I do another expansion: Normal[Series[p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 +(L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 + ( L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2] /. {( L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2 -> [Lambda] (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t])/c^2, ( L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 -> [Lambda] (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2, (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2 -> [Lambda] (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t])/c^2}, {[Lambda], 0, 1}]] /.[Lambda] -> 1 /.1/c^3 -> 0]

Comment: and this is the final results: p2[t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c] + (L2p[t] Derivative[1][L2][t] Derivative[1][p2][t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2 + (L2[t] Derivative[1][L3][t] Derivative[1][p2][t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2 + ( L2p[t] Derivative[1][L3][t] Derivative[1][p2][t - L2[t]/c - L2p[t]/c - L3[t]/c])/c^2

Comment: I was wondering if you know a way to automatised the calculation instead of doing it manually step by step, every time i expand around Li[t]/c ->\lambda*Li[t]/c or (Li[t] dot[Lj[t])/c^2 -> \Lambda*(Li[t]dot[Lj[t])/c^2, thank you in advance for your help, I know I put it in a confused way but i do not know how to include the code in a different way!

Comment: @Martina I'd advise you to incorporate it in an edit section of your question

Comment: ! thanks' I followed your suggestion! tell me if it is clear :) I am new of mathematica so I am learning!

Comment: Hey thank you so much! you are really kind! i was checking your results and comparing that with the code i did manually, there are some differences,I have upload a picture of my mathematica code's on my previews answer...at the end of the text there is shown what I got and what you get...do you know why we are getting different results? I can say that you did not have done any Taylor expansion for L2[t-L3[t]/c] around L3[t]/c ( line input[91] and input[92]  of my code)